# How kernels recognize sin_zero (sockaddr_in structure) pushed

Tags: assembly, kernel

According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277079/need-i-push-sin-zero-sockaddr-in, it's my election reserve the space of sin_zero in the stack (sub esp, 8) or not. If I push, ok, I've pushed 16 bytes (sizeof(sockaddr_in)), but if I don't reserve the 8 bytes of sin_zero how kernels know?

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    short            sin_family;   // e.g. AF_INET, AF_INET6
    unsigned short   sin_port;     // e.g. htons(3490)
    struct in_addr   sin_addr;     // see struct in_addr, below
    char             sin_zero[8];  // zero this if you want to
};
```

Comment: Kernel doesn't know. You stated that `sin_zero` is not used, so it doesn't matter. Note that it's at the end of the structure, so whatever is on the stack at that memory location will be visible in `sin_zero`. Let's hope it really isn't used...

Comment: Functions generally don't know whether pointer arguments that you pass to them are valid - they just assume that they are. So if the function in question tried to access all of the `sockaddr_in` struct you could be in trouble. Do you really have a good reason not to allocate the structure properly? Also, wouldn't it be easier to just have a `sockaddr_in` in your `.data` or `.bss` section instead of allocating it on the stack?

Comment: But the kernel don't pop anyway these 8 bytes?